# Ошибка каскадного обновления при создании таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Когда я пытаюсь создать таблицу выводится сообщение: 
Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 136
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__ProductCa__Categ__703EA55A' on table 'ProductCategoryAmount' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 136
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Скрипт создаваемой таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductCategoryAmount
(
    ProductId INT NOT NULL,
    CategoryId INT NOT NULL,
    [Count] FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY (ProductId) REFERENCES Products (ProductId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId) REFERENCES NormCategory (CategoryId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Если убрать UPDATE CASCADE на таблицу NormCategory, таблица создается нормально.
Скрипт NormCategory:

```
CREATE TABLE NormCategory
(
    CategoryId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CategoryName nvarchar NOT NULL,
    NormId INT,
    IsBasicCategory BIT DEFAULT 1,
    FOREIGN KEY (NormId) REFERENCES Norms (NormId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Проследите цепочку референсов дальше. Скорее всего выйдете на таблицу Products.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin понял сейчас проверю, спасибо.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin проверил цепочка прерывается на таблице Orders в ней нет ссылок.

Comment: Значит проверьте цепочку по ProductId с выходом в итоге на NormCategory

Comment: @DenisRubashkin да нашел зацикливание, спасибо большое за помощь.